# update page informations or submit to new page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a welcome page with a dropdown list to select cities. 
By default, the first city of the list is used to display quick informations on the city.

Validating the selected city brings to a new page dedicated to this city.
This works fine.

What I'd like to do, is that selecting a new city without validation, would modify the city informations on the welcome page.

[image]

Here is my PHP code:

```
    $db = app::getdatabase();

    $checkinformations= new informations();

    $town="city1";

    if(isset($_POST['submit']) AND isset($_POST['cities']))
    {   
        app::redirect("/city/$town/");
    }

    require_once'inc/welcome_page.php';
```

And the welcome_page.php:

```
        <h1>Welcome</h1>

        <form role="form" action="#" method="POST">  

          <select name="cities" id="city" >
          <option value="city1">city1</option>
          <option value="city2">city2</option>
          <option value="city3">city3</option>
          </select>

          <button type="submit" class="btn" name="submit"></button> 

        </form>

        <div> 
        <?php echo  $checkinformations->informations($db,$town);?>
        </div>
```

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: the questions is how is the best way to refresh the php code to update the city and update the informations() function without submitting the form.

Comment: looks like my question is not very popular and will make me loose my small amount of points :) should I remove it? is my question to general?

Comment: I think it's best to try again with a new question. Maybe you can pinpoint the actual problem a bit more. Leave out the functional aspects (such as `validate`) and substitute this with the relevant technical parts. Make sure the actual question is very clear to ensure the best answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display selected city information on change on same page then you have to use AJAX. First take one blank div with id. and dump ajax response into that.
I edit the code to execute "Change" event, I put $('#city').trigger('change'); this line before closing "OnReady function" and after onchange function method, because method is going to define before to trigger.

```
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <form role="form" action="#" method="POST">  

      <select name="cities" id="city" >
      <option value="city1">city1</option>
      <option value="city2">city2</option>
      <option value="city3">city3</option>
      </select>

      <button type="submit" class="btn" name="submit"></button> 

    </form>

    <div id="cityInfo">  </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#city").on("change", function(){
        $.ajax({
                        type: 'post',
                        url: 'citydetails.php',
                        data: {cityname: $("#city").val()},
                        success: function (data) {
                                $('#cityInfo').html(data);
                        }
                });
             });
$('#city').trigger('change'); //From here you can trigger city change event.
            });
    </script>
```

Comment: thx for help. I created the citydetails.php, and tried to get the city with $_POST['cities']. it seems to not work (but the code works if I define a value of  city in the citydetails.php). As I am just discovering Ajax, is it the right way to get the update city post? also, is there a way to give a default value before on change?

Comment: ok now I have the code working. I should had used $_POST['cityname']. I just need to find out how to give a default value before an on change event occurs.

Comment: By default you can set single city as selected in dropdown. And in on ready loop 
$(document).ready(function(){ $("#city").trigger("change");  ...... });
add this line so that first time on change event will trigger and function will be execute. Try this one.

Comment: I didn't manage to make this work. Is  $("#city").trigger("change");  supposed to trigger a first change when the wleocme page is first loaded so that  $("#city").on("change", function(){ is loaded without having to manually select a city? could you update your code with this solution? I probably write something in an incorrect way.

Comment: What works but is probably not very good code is https://jsfiddle.net/4aaa7goa/

Comment: @michltm sorry for late reply, I edit the answer please check it.

Answer (score 0):

Using [jQuery AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). Just an Example

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

     $("#city").on("change", function(){

       //Getting Data from Server using AJAX

       $.ajax({

          url: "getCityDetails.php",
          type: "post",
          data: {city: $("#city").val()},
          success: function(data){

              //Update City Details in Homepage

          }

       });


     })

  });
```

Comment: Why should the OP "use jQuery AJAX"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.